# Cannot find and read file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am completely new to Java and I am
 using somebody elses code to read a binary file
but the file will not open. I am running the code in Eclipse under Windows 10 
the file is called 
bookDeepDist.dat 
I have put it in the project folder. The full path name which I have also tried (without success ) is 
C:\Users\Alan\eclipse-workspace\readDatabase\bookDeepDist.dat

The code that fails is:

```
public void openBook() throws IOException {

    file = getClass().getResourceAsStream(BOOKPATH[bookNr]);
    if (file == null)
        throw (new IOException("Could not open File "+BOOKPATH[bookNr]));
}
```

The error message is: 
Could not open File bookDeepDist.dat

so it seems to be trying to open the correct file.
Can anybody give me any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: if you're on windows and have the file open somewhere you can get an error like that

Comment: I do not believe it is open elsewhere. but to avoid doubt I will completely reboot and try again. I will let you know later

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that getResourceAsStream() looks in the classpath of the running Java program. That's why it is working, when you put the file in the project folder. What you want, is a stream of the file outside of the program's classpath.

Instead of

```
file = getClass().getResourceAsStream(BOOKPATH[bookNr]);
```

try using

```
file = new FileInputStream(BOOKPATH[bookNr]);
```

Comment: You seem to think that it is working when I put it in the project folder. Unfortunately it is not. I put it there when I could not get it to work elsewhere. The class and function is part of a project called readDatabase and I thought the "working directory" of the project was C:\Users\Alan\eclipse-workspace\readDatabase. if that is not correct where is it. The file is a binary file and I believe needs to be opened as a stream.  will your suggestion do that? I will try it tonight and see. thanks

Comment: Ah ok, my fault. As I said, the program with `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` expects the file to be in the classpath. This is normally used to refer to files you bundle within a JAR or similar. You could define the classpath when starting the program, or you could copy the file to the folder, where your compiled classes are.

But that's not what I would do. Better use `new FileInputStream(filename)`, which gives you a stream to a file anywhere on the system.

Comment: Sorry I could not get it to work. The compiler could not find iFileInputtream. I googled and imported a couple of things and it still could not find it. I started out thinking that getting this database read,decyphered and printed out to file would be simpler if I installed Java and rean the program that I had. Today I gave up, I just do not know enough about the environment. In about half an hour I created the program in Pytho, copying the decryption bit from java . So thank you for your help but I am going to stay in my  save world of Python and C++.